# Sort a dictionary of Currencies into groups with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a Dictionary of Currencies:

```
Dictionary<string, string>
        _currencies = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
                        .Select(c => new RegionInfo(c.LCID))
                        .Where(ri => ri != null)
                        .GroupBy(ri => ri.ISOCurrencySymbol)
                        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.First().CurrencyEnglishName);
```

I want to sort these into a group of Popular Currencies and the Rest.

So far I am doing this, but I don't like it:

```
List<string> popularCurrencies = new List<string>
{
    "GBP", "EUR", "USD", "AUD", "CNY", "INR", "SGD"
};

List<Currency> popular = _currencies
    .Where(kvp => popularCurrencies.Contains(kvp.Key))
    .Select(kvp => new Currency
    {
        Id = kvp.Key,
        Name = kvp.Key + " - " + kvp.Value,
        Category = "Popular"
    })
    .ToList();

List<Currency> other = _currencies
    .Where(kvp => !popularCurrencies.Contains(kvp.Key))
    .Select(kvp => new Currency
    {
        Id = kvp.Key,
        Name = kvp.Key + " - " + kvp.Value,
        Category = "All"
    })
    .ToList();

List<Currency> all = popular.Concat(other).ToList();

public class Currency 
{
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

I was thinking I could get the 2 linq queries and the Concat into 1 line.

UPDATE:

I added ordering to the Popular Currencies.  I am wondering if there is an easy way to sort the rest of them.

```
                Dictionary<string, int> popularCurrencies = new Dictionary<string, int>() {
                {"GBP", 1},{"EUR", 2},{"USD", 3},{"AUD", 4},{"CNY", 5},{"INR", 6},{"SGD", 7}
            };
                var all = _currencies.Select(kvp => new Currency
            {
                Id = kvp.Key,
                Name = kvp.Key + " - " + kvp.Value,
                Category = popularCurrencies.Any(c => c.Key == kvp.Key) ? "Popular" : "All"
            }).OrderByDescending(c => c.Category).OrderBy(c => popularCurrencies.ContainsKey(c.Id) ? popularCurrencies[c.Id] : int.MaxValue).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var all = _currencies.Select(kvp => new Currency
{
    Id = kvp.Key,
    Name = kvp.Key + " - " + kvp.Value,
    Category = popularCurrencies.Any(c => c == kvp.Key) ? "Popular" : "All"    
}).ToList()
```

**Added:**
If you want popular currencies first you can add `OrderByDescending`:

```
var all = _currencies.Select(kvp => new Currency
{
    Id = kvp.Key,
    Name = kvp.Key + " - " + kvp.Value,
    Category = popularCurrencies.Any(c => c == kvp.Key) ? "Popular" : "All"    
}).OrderByDescending(c => c.Category).ToList()
```

Comment: This looks nice but I think it misses the fact, that the popular Currencies should be at the beginning of the resulting list. So just add an OrderBy for the Category with Descending order.

Comment: Additionally I want to order the popular category by the order of the List of popularCurrencies....I don't mind about the ordering of the rest of the currencies.  Maybe I should ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

You can group the currencies by their occurrence in the list of popular ones, and then flatten (`SelectMany`) the two groups into `Currency` objects:

```
_currencies.GroupBy(x => popularCurrencies.Contains(x.Key) ? "Popular" : "All")
           .SelectMany(g => g.Select(x => new Currency 
                                          { 
                                              Id = x.Key, 
                                              Name = x.Key + " - " + x.Value, 
                                              Category = g.Key 
                                          }))
```

If you use `Select` in stead of `SelectMany` the query will return two groups. The title of your question suggests that that's what you're after.

If you want to order one group by a specific order you can do

```
_currencies.GroupBy(x => popularCurrencies.Contains(x.Key) ? "Popular" : "All")
           .SelectMany(g => g.OrderBy(x => g.Key == "All" 
                                                      ? x.OrderByProperty 
                                                      : "" // or e.g. 0
                             .Select(x => new Currency 
                                          { 
                                              Id = x.Key, 
                                              Name = x.Key + " - " + x.Value, 
                                              Category = g.Key 
                                          }))
```

Comment: This works, but I need to add an order to it as the popular are at the end.  This might be useful if I decide to group the Rest by continent or something else.  Is there a way to sort each part of the select.

Comment: Yes, please see the addition.